# First Login: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I have made a Java webapp with Spring, Hibernate and MySQL. It runs correctly, but in the first attempt to connect, I have the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed: 
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed: 
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:317)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy31.getTodosUsuariosList(Unknown Source)
    com.companyname.springapp.service.SimpleAnonimoManager.identificarse(SimpleAnonimoManager.java:21)
    com.companyname.springapp.web.IdentificarseFormController.onSubmit(IdentificarseFormController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed: 
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:96)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:317)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy31.getTodosUsuariosList(Unknown Source)
    com.companyname.springapp.service.SimpleAnonimoManager.identificarse(SimpleAnonimoManager.java:21)
    com.companyname.springapp.web.IdentificarseFormController.onSubmit(IdentificarseFormController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 4,665,488 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor139.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3670)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3559)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4110)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5333)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:331)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:317)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:91)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:317)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy31.getTodosUsuariosList(Unknown Source)
    com.companyname.springapp.service.SimpleAnonimoManager.identificarse(SimpleAnonimoManager.java:21)
    com.companyname.springapp.web.IdentificarseFormController.onSubmit(IdentificarseFormController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3119)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3570)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3559)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4110)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5333)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:331)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:317)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:91)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:317)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy31.getTodosUsuariosList(Unknown Source)
    com.companyname.springapp.service.SimpleAnonimoManager.identificarse(SimpleAnonimoManager.java:21)
    com.companyname.springapp.web.IdentificarseFormController.onSubmit(IdentificarseFormController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.32 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
```

It happens only in the first attempt. If I reload the page or I try to identify again, it runs correctly.

I search in the Internet a lot of possible solutions, I try some of them, but it doesn't run yet. Yesterday I try a solution that it seems correctly, and when I upload it, it works well, but today the error appeared again, so I don't know how I can do.

Those are my configuration files:

jdbc.properties

```
hibernate.generate_statistics = true
hibernate.show_sql = true

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=pass
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.companyname.springapp.domain.Contrato" />
        <mapping class="com.companyname.springapp.domain.ContratoDraftInicial" />
        <mapping class="com.companyname.springapp.domain.Derecho" />
        <mapping class="com.companyname.springapp.domain.Equipo" />
        <mapping class="com.companyname.springapp.domain.EstadisticaEquipo" />
        <mapping class="com.companyname.springapp.domain.EstadisticaJugador" />
        <mapping class="com.companyname.springapp.domain.Jugador" />
        <mapping class="com.companyname.springapp.domain.Usuario" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.web" />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
    </bean>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- holding properties for database connectivity /-->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration /-->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.service" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<!-- 
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <display-name>Springapp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

To call the database, I do this (I put a example of class):
EquipoDaoImp.java

```
@Repository(value = "equipoDao")
public class EquipoDaoImp implements EquipoDao {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public EquipoDaoImp(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Integer getIdEquipo(String nombreUsuario) {
        return (Integer) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Equipo e order by e.id")
                        .uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

Any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that MySQL or a firewall is killing off your inactive connections that are hanging around in your jdbc connection pool for long periods of time:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 
The last packet successfully received from the server was 4,665,488 milliseconds ago.
```

Check the value of [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) on MySQL.

You can play around with [DBCP settings](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) e.g. validationQuery, testOnBorrow and testWhileIdle.

A a confuguration that is 'belt and braces', and will probably solve your problem at the expense of performance is:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
  <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

The above will test connections every time you borrow from the pool.

Comment: I put this that you say. I tried to enter, and I could enter at the first time. But maybe tomorrow I will be sure if this is the correct solution if I can enter at the first time again. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ok. After 2 days, it runs correctly. That was the problem. Thanks :)